# Bootstrap hamburger menu z-index and styling issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design my first responsive site and am having issues with the navigation.  I've got everything somewhat working up to point where the hamburger kicks in.  At that point, the drop down menu goes behind the form elements and I don't understand enough at this point to change the styling without affecting the normal navigation.

It seems that most of the things I've looked at are using the standard BootStrap elements with little more than color changes.  I need to change the height of the nav bar (along with the hamburger), center the nav but when the site goes mobile, the nav dropdown would need to change font and background colors and text alignment.

I've got a bootply running and will continue to research as I go.  I know I have a long way to go but would appreciate a helping hand getting me over this hurdle.

The bootply is at http://www.bootply.com/xtOWUEP1bw.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should include your code in this post on SO, don't just link to bootply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need z-index and background color. 
Put z-index in .navbar and put background color in .navbar-collapse.in like below;

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 10;
}

.navbar-collapse.in{
    background:#fff
}
```